# Is it possible to mix transparent and solid colors in CSS3?

Tags: css

Is it possible to dynamically make a transparent background from a solid and a transparent color in CSS3? For example:

```
<div class="red trans1">
CONTENT
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.red {
background: #FF0000;
}
.trans1
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

In this case, solid color will totally cover the transparency. Of course, I mean using different properties (`background`, `background-color`, etc).

I have 10 solid colors, and want to create 10 level of transparency for each. If individually making the transparent color for each color, it needs 100 CSS classes; e.g.:

```
.red1 {
.background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
.red2 {
.background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
.red3 {
.background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
....
.blue1 {
.background: rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
}
.blue2 {
.background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}
.blue3 {
.background: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
}
```

I am looking for a dynamic way to mix the solid color and a transparent background.

Comment: What do you mean by "level of transparency"?

Comment: I don't understand entirely what you are going for... one div cannot have two colors, but you can put two separate divs on top of one another with two different colors.

Comment: have you got content into these divs ? if no, you can use opacity property that is independent to color

Comment: @BoltClock I added an example to clarify the issue.

Comment: @watson I can put two `div`s, but solid `div` will cover the transparency.

Comment: @JeromeC. yes I have text content, and opacity will affect the text too.

Comment: i cannot imagine what do you imagine. why not layer those divs?  and the one with the solid color at the back. two color property for same element is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean [gradients](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) or [transitions](http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transition.html)?

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut I want the entire `DIV` preserves the transparency. The background is deep behind.

Comment: @TimS. NONE. I want transparency of the `DIV` to show the background.

Comment: Maybe a visual example will help illustrate this better...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Pure CSS

Yes, you can disassociate the color and transparency by creative use of pseudo-elements. For example, [this fiddle demonstrates the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/SngdD/2/) (notice I have arranged everything based on the `:after` pseudo-element):

**HTML**

```
<div class="opBkg red op10">Red 10%</div>
<div class="opBkg red op50">Red 50%</div>
<div class="opBkg blue op80">Blue 80%</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.opBkg {
  position: relative;
}

.opBkg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.red:after {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue:after {
  background-color: blue;
}
.op10:after {
  opacity: .1;  
}
.op50:after {
  opacity: .5;  
}
.op80:after {
  opacity: .8;  
}
```

You would have 10 opacity rules, however many colors you want, and then the overarching `opBkg` class to set things up.

Comment: Thanks but it was discussed before with an answer. `opacity` will affect the entire `DIV` including text content, not providing transparent background.

Comment: +1 @All Not in this case; this use of `opacity` only affects the pseudo-element. This is pretty clever.

Comment: @All: Yes, as Jonathan Sampson states, my solution is only affecting the pseudo-element which is getting positioned behind the `div` by the `z-index: -1` which makes it the "background." Look at the fiddle link to see the result.

Comment: @All has not even opened the fiddle :/ Btw +1, i totally love this approach :D

Comment: hm, i thought about opacity on pseudoelements, but didn't think this through. Nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to explicitly create the 10 rules, or have a preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)/[Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/opacity/) do it for you.

The only other option would be to set the opacity dynamically with JavaScript based on some attribute indicating degree of transparency. The following uses jQuery to accomplish this:

```html
<div class="red" data-opacity=".75"></div>
<div class="red" data-opacity=".50"></div>
<div class="red" data-opacity=".25"></div>
```

```js
$(".red").css("background-color", function (index, old) {
    var data = { 
        color: old.match(/[0-9, ]+/), 
        alpha: $(this).data("opacity") 
    };
    return "rgba(" + data.color + ", " + data.alpha + ")";
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/WYDJL/

Comment: his problem is having 10 colors x 10 transparencies = 100 rules;)